# My Android app release is too big than expected

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have created a simple android app to download the whatsapp status

```
I have completed all the functionalities.then the app size is less than 5MB
```

After that i added a third party plugin to add my app name to the downloaded video files as watermark

```
i used ffmpeg to add water mark in the video
```

But after that my app release size reached around 20MB.

```
I used minifyEnabled true to shrink the code.but doesn't worked
```

How to reduce my release size

Comment: Hope you are using app bundle instead of apk and after that  if the size increased by library then you can't do anything with that . But I would recommend you to analyze the apk once see which resources taking how much space

Comment: Compile your own ffmpeg only enabling the components you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use and app bundle to reduce the size. Find more information on google developers official side.
[Reduce apk size](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size)